# react app crashes while remote debug js in expo 40.0.0

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

**This is the logs while crashing**

15 verbose cwd F:\clickify updated\clickify

16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042

17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"

18 verbose node v14.10.1

19 verbose npm  v6.14.11

20 error code ELIFECYCLE

21 error errno 1

22 error @ start: `expo start`

22 error Exit status 1

23 error Failed at the @ start script.

23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

** This is my App.js**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**This is my package.json**

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**This is the error**

```
Opening exp://127.0.0.1:19000 on Pixel_3a_XL_API_30_2
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 46214ms.
Running application on Android SDK built for x86.
info Launching Dev Tools...
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:464:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Vishal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-15T09_26_48_544Z-debug.log
```

If anyone know how to solve this please give suggestions.

P.S. :-Also tried downgrading SDK version to 39.0.3. That also didn't work

Comment: Can you please upload your code

Comment: I just simply created a new expo project using expo init [project name]. Since in previous project debug crashes tried downgraded that one to 39.0.3. That doesn't work, then I created a new project, it's again crashes on debugging

Comment: please upload your code

Comment: uploaded the code